# angular2 route resolve gaurd - how to pass variables to the service

Tags: angular

I am using angular rc2 and have a question about route resolve guard.

This is my resolve service.  It works fine.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, Resolve, ActivatedRouteSnapshot } from '@angular/router';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { ApiService } from '../api_service/api.service';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/take';
import { BasicSetup } from './basic_setup'
@Injectable()
export class BasicSetupResolve implements Resolve<any> {

  constructor(private _apiService: ApiService, private router: Router) {}



    resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): Observable<any> | Promise<any> | any {
        let id = route.params['id'];
        let model_id = id;
        let endpoint='/test/model/basic';
        return new Promise((resolve) => { this._apiService.getModel(endpoint,model_id,false).subscribe(api_object => {
                if (api_object) {
                    return resolve(api_object); 
                } else { // id not found
                    this.router.navigateByUrl('/dashboard(content:models/basic/' +  model_id +')');
                    return false;
                }
                });

        });
      }
    }
```

Here is my app.route.ts

```
{ path: 'models/basic/:id', component: mesaBasicComponent,canActivate: [AuthGuard], resolve: {results: BasicSetupResolve},outlet:'content' },
```

I need to pass a variable to make more dynamic because by endpoint changes else I would have to make a separate service for each endpoint:

```
  let endpoint='/test/model/basic';
```

How would I pass that to the service?

Comment: How about passing data object and retrieving it from resolve service?

Comment: but how? Seems I have to pass from the route resolve: {results: BasicSetupResolve} what would that look like?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pass data to the resolver:

in your route configuration:

```
{
  path: 'your-path',
  component: YourComponent,
  data: {
    someKey: 'someValue',
  },
  resolve: {
    someKey: YourResolver
  },
}
```

In your resolver

```
@Injectable()
export class YourResolver implements Resolve<any> {

  // ... 

  resolve(route:ActivatedRouteSnapshot):Observable<any> | Promise<any> | any {

    console.log(route.data['someKey']);

    // ... 
  }
}
```